# Sharing Image + Text from App to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

Hello I have been able to implement a function that allows me too share image + text via email or other common social media platforms however my one problem so far has been facebook.  I just does not work for facebook, I did some research and found out that i order to share image + text content I will have to download and use the facebook sdk in my app.

Now my question is this, when I tap the share button a dialog slides from the bottom showing you the platforms you can share the content on; Email, Whatsapp, Facebook etc.  If I do integrate this facebook SDK am I going to have to create a separate button to share content via facebook?

Comment: Share what text? Where?

Comment: What do you mean what text and where? The text doesn't matter and I have already stated where in my question.

Comment: Then read https://developers.facebook.com/policy which say you are not allowed to prefill the message. But I have no idea if you want to prefill the message or something else because you haven't said